# how to structure your code to have a form step by step with angular 7 and bootstrap 4?

Tags: angular

when the precedent step is valid before to pass to next? for exemple
[image]

Comment: what is exactly the problem or what do you want to achieve. if you want this kind of functionality there is a component in angular material.

Comment: What have you already tried? Did you get stuck somewhere? Do you have any code to we can take a look at? Remember: Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service!

Comment: If you are looking for a library for that, here you go: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-archwizard

Comment: Along with the problem you should **include the code you have up until this point** (*make some effort to answer your problem/question as [so] is not a code writing service*). After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

I think the best and quickest way to implement a perfect multi-step form is to use [Stepper](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview) [image]provided by `angular-material`. Its by far the best option.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

1. A route for each step
2. Each route redirect to a different component
3. Each component has a form

You can validate the navigation using a custom Guard

```
{ path: 'step/1', component: MyStep1Component, canDeactivate: [MyGuard] }
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I was thinking of an approach. one in a single component but yours using multiple component is better strutted